# What web server to use with solr

Tags: solr, webserver

Am a beginner and wants to implement sorl for search with a mvc web application.

Witch web server is the fastest and most secure to use for sorl?

Jetty, tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is fine.

Solr uses Jetty to make the initial setup and configuration process easier and ships with it. But that does not mean that Jetty is a bad choice for production deployment. If your
The organization already has a standard Java web-application platform, then Solr will work
with it - Tomcat, weblogic, JBoss etc. But if you have some choice then use Jetty. It's fast,
stable, mature, and easy to administer and customize. In fact, Google uses Jetty for their
App Engine—see www.infoq.com/news/2009/08/google-chose-jetty/.

If you want to use Tomcat solr has steps to setup , its easy : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat

So the answer depends, security, what your organization allows. Solr is a war file all it cares is for a Servlet Container.

Comment: Hope you have time to answer one more question.
In the "Spring Data Solr Tutorial: Configuration" from the link you gave me they talk about "embedded Solr server" and "HTTP Solr server"

How does these relate to the webserver for example Jetty?

Are there two servers one webserver (jetty or tomcat) and one http server?

Comment: embedded solr server is to run solr as part of a standalone java program. Most people do not need that, thought it has  some interesting usages. The one that runs on jetty, tomcat etc is "HTTP Solr server".

Comment: So you mean that there is one webserver jetty (witch is a http-server), and another HTTP-server (sorl http-server), two http-servers.

Why does it need two webservers?

Or is it jetty or tomcat or whatever that is receiving calls to the sorl-index that is refered to as sorl http-server. Just like iis for asp?